# postgresql or Mongodb for storing location data (lat & long) and search based on?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, location, latitude-longitude

I have a system that I like to find nearest people to a person based on latitude and longitude data. 
I know how to work with location data in Mongodb and how to find nearest people for every person by radius and etc.
but I don`t know what if I have a large number of user in system and it is possible to crash my system with query on location data in postgresql?
which dbms is great for working with location data, Postgresql or Mongodb ???
I appreciate for your help.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of query you're talking about is called "KNN" or "K-nearest-neighbor" which PostgreSQL supports directly using a GIST index.  Even better, true KNN is supported with PostGIS for doing KNN on lat/long (aka geospatial) data.  Here's a good presentation on using KNN in PostgreSQL with PostGIS:

https://www.hagander.net/talks/Find%20your%20neighbours.pdf

You can read more about the KNN capabilities in PostGIS here:

https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html

I won't speak to which is database is better for your particular workload since I don't know it directly and I'd be a bit biased anyway, as you might guess given the links above.  What I will say is that PostgreSQL is very efficient and very fast at performing exactly these kinds of queries and scales very well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance.